# how to get text by moving cursor by selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get the text from each bar in the following plot.

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('d:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://dph.georgia.gov/covid-19-daily-status-report')
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#covid19dashdph > iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/div')
print(element.text) # return ''

# action = ActionChains(driver)
# action.move_by_offset(1, 1)
```

My question is:

1. how to get the text value because I saw the text in the source page
2. How to move mouse cursor one bar by the other to get the next daily case number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just clicked on the svg tag and printed it's value which was in a tag on the site.

```
driver.get('https://dph.georgia.gov/covid-19-daily-status-report')
frame=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#covid19dashdph > iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

svg=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, " div.MuiBox-root.jss326 > div > svg")))
svg.click()
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.MuiBox-root.jss326 > div > div")))
print(element.text)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs

07Jun20
Confirmed Cases 524
7-day Moving Average 720.7

The html tag consists of:

```
<div class="c3-tooltip-container" style="position: absolute; pointer-events: none; display: none; top: 529.5px; left: 74.5px;">
<table class="c3-tooltip">
<tbody>
<tr><th colspan="2">07Jun20</th></tr>
<tr class="c3-tooltip-name--Confirmed-Cases">
<td class="name"><span style="background-color:#33a3ff"></span>Confirmed Cases</td>
<td class="value">524</td></tr>
<tr class="c3-tooltip-name--\37 -day-Moving-Average">
<td class="name"><span style="background-color:#ffcc32"></span>7-day Moving Average</td>
<td class="value">720.7</td>
</tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much and I learned a lot from you! Two follow-up questions: 1) why to click the 'svg' tag, to activate the plot area?; 2) how do I loop through all the bars and get numbers by each day?

Comment: The tag on the bottom needs a click or move to and it repopulates it's own value. i just made it click the svg to do a demo value.